# Linux: do syscalls change?

Tags: linux, kernel, system-calls

Syscalls are the user-space facing interface of the kernel. A user process usually does not call them directly but use libc to do that. libc either just provides a thin wrapper around the syscall or does some more work as in the case of `fork()` and `exec()`

So my question is - does the syscall interface to the kernel ever change between versions of the kernel in a non-backwards compatible way? Or is it once a syscall is established, it will never change?

Comment: Allow me to quote from the `open(2)` man page: "**CONFORMING TO**".

Comment: Why exactly are you asking???

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I want to compile my application with a static libc like musl and be sure it never breaks :)

Comment: "never" has no meaning in IT. But your app probably won't break for perhaps a dozen of years (or slightly less). If this is not enough, make it free software (with the hope than someone will adapt the source code to relevant standards in 2030 or 2040)!

Comment: Any answer to this question, in the context of Linux, must include the kernel developer's motto: "Never break userspace". This is a major policy over which Linus has repeatedly berated even kernel maintainers. For more detail, read [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/235335/why-is-there-a-linux-kernel-policy-to-never-break-user-space).

Answer (score 6):

A [syscall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall) is, from the application code perspective, an elementary atomic operation (it is a "virtual machine instruction"). See also [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

The [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) specifies how exactly it is happenning. For x86-64 you can find it [here](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf). See also [x86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions).

For some syscalls, recent kernels provide the [vdso(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html) to make them faster.

The Linux kernel tries hard to keep compatibility at the binary level. It is rumored that a 15 years old (statically linked) [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable should run unchanged on the most recent kernels.

However, in practice, you don't *directly* do syscalls in your code (because you need to do that in assembly, see [Linux assembly howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/)). You very often use some `libc` for that (e.g. the [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/libc.html), or the [MUSL libc](http://musl-libc.org/)). For several good reasons you generally dynamically link your program to `libc.so`. Then you might have -in the very long run- some incompatibilities issues (some binary programs linked to an old `libc`  might not run with a much newer -or much older- one).

Answer (score 2):

Big changes aren't to be expected because of the following reasons:

1. Although they will be called mostly through the libc, the libc can be changed - it created compatibility problems between the kernel and the libc versions, which needs to be avoided.
2. Syscalls are standardised exactly as the libc calls.

The libc version of `fork()` and `exec()` is really small, they to exactly as the syscalls. Maybe you are thinking on `system()`, which practically fork-s, calls a shell with exec and waits its termination.

There are also syscalls with much lower importance, they aren't really liked by Linus and the core team, for example the syscalls starting with _*reiser4*... , they have much bigger chance to change in the future.

But the standard syscalls, for example `sys_open`, `sys_close`, etc. won't change in the nearest future.

---

There is also one thing, which can change, and it is not the syscalls, but the method how can be called. In the ancients, linux/i386 used this by an `int 0x80`, where the number of the syscals had to put in `eax`. Since then came better/faster solutions for this as well, for example there is a CPU-specific `SYSENTER` asm-opcode, which also can be used. Their usability is cpu-specific, thus it was one of the first times, when the kernel needed to provide the *user space code*, how can be its syscalls called. If you type a `cat /proc/$$/maps`, you will see at end a `[vdso]` or a `[vsyscall]` memory area, this is. Older kernels (maybe before 2.4?) didn't have it.

Comment: I was just reading blog that covers exactly that https://blog.packagecloud.io/the-definitive-guide-to-linux-system-calls/#:~:text=System%20calls%20are%20how%20a,file%20IO%2C%20and%20much%20more.